# Cannot sent SMTP email after updating to EE 2.7.3 from 2.5.5

Tags: email, smtp

So i have EE sending SMTP mail via a remote server which was all working fine in EE 2.5.5 but now i have upgraded to 2.7.3 it's not having it at all!

The error i get is:

An Error Was Encountered
Unable to send email at this time.

```
220 brightmail.redacted.local ESMTP Symantec Messaging Gateway 

hello: 250-brightmail.redacted.local says EHLO to 111.111.111.111:41353
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-SIZE 15728640
250-8BITMIME
250 PIPELINING
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 500 5.5.2 unrecognized command 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

I have got this stuff already configured:

```
$config['email_newline']    = "\r\n";
$config['email_crlf']       = "\r\n";
```

And nothing else i try has any effect.

Any help would be grand!

Comment: have you tried sending it through a different server? Anything in the mailserver error logs?

Comment: I have to send via this SMTP, i cannot use another otherwise i'd be all over it!

Comment: Try sending it through Mandrill via SMTP

Comment: Sorry, i meant i have to use this companies SMTP!

Comment: Yeah but just as a test. To see if the problem is EE or the mailserver you are trying to use.

Comment: No, it's not the mailserver, i don't need to test.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using SMTP with EE, I'd recommend using Escort (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/escort) with a third-party 'transactional' email service like Mandrill (http://mandrill.com). We've also had issues with SMTP and PHP mail in EE (particularly Gmail deliverability), which the third-party system solved.  Escort is super-easy to set up, and you get the benefits of the third-party system (better deliverability, batch sending, reporting, etc.).

Someone else may be able to specifically address your issues with SMTP, but I still think it's worth considering the third-party route.